# Javascript dataTables Add variable into data columns

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using dataTables to populate my tables and I need to insert some static data into the table.

So I now have this:

```
jQuery('#mytable').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { "users": "id" },
        { "somethingelse": "valuehere" }
    ]
});
```

Is it possible to add a variable to valuehere? for example:

```js
var dataSet = [['userid', 'something else'],['userid', 'something else']];
var myVariableHere = "some variable";

jQuery('#mytable').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { "users": "id" },
    { "somethingelse": myVariableHere }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="mytable" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: This should be possible if the myVariableHere has been formatted properly.

Comment: did you tried it ? as first look , it seems to work. And if the question is simply "Is it possible to add a variable to valuehere? ", then i think you are the best placed person to tell this

Comment: `var myVariableHere = 'whatever'`
`jQuery('#mytable').DataTable(function (myVariableHere) { ... }`

should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the variable isn't a problem, but your columns need to each have a "title" property.

```js
var dataSet = [['userid', 'something else'],['userid', 'something else']];
var myVariableHere = "some variable";

jQuery('#mytable').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "id" },
    { title: myVariableHere }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="mytable" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: How do I do it if the data looks like this: { "data": "data.name", "title": "Names" } ?